# The connector does not work after stopping the Debezium Connector with Ctrl+C and restart the connector again

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I use Debezium MySQL connector to capture change data from my database. It could work well previously. However, now, after I stopped my connector and restarted it, the connector does not work. I encountered this issue today, and I believe it worked well yesterday. Can someone help with it? Thank you so much!
These are the error messages.

```
[2021-02-11 01:19:13,581] INFO Kafka version: 6.0.1-ccs (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:117)
[2021-02-11 01:19:13,581] INFO Kafka commitId: 9c1fbb3db1e0d69d (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:118)
[2021-02-11 01:19:13,581] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1613027953581 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:119)
[2021-02-11 01:19:13,582] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=test-location-connector-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:481)
[2021-02-11 01:19:13,582] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=test-location-connector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:498)
[2021-02-11 01:19:13,582] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=test-location-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:187)
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task io.debezium.relational.history.KafkaDatabaseHistory$$Lambda$732/0x000000080062a840@5d307667 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4d465813[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2055)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:825)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1355)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute(Executors.java:687)
    at io.debezium.relational.history.KafkaDatabaseHistory.checkTopicSettings(KafkaDatabaseHistory.java:382)
    at io.debezium.relational.history.KafkaDatabaseHistory.exists(KafkaDatabaseHistory.java:362)
    at io.debezium.relational.HistorizedRelationalDatabaseSchema.recover(HistorizedRelationalDatabaseSchema.java:45)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask.validateAndLoadDatabaseHistory(MySqlConnectorTask.java:305)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask.start(MySqlConnectorTask.java:92)
    at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:106)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[2021-02-11 01:19:13,583] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=test-location-connector-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:188)
[2021-02-11 01:19:13,583] INFO Stopping down connector (io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask:192)
[2021-02-11 01:19:13,584] INFO Connection gracefully closed (io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection:946)
[2021-02-11 01:19:13,585] INFO [Producer clientId=MysqlTest2-dbhistory] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1189)
[2021-02-11 01:19:13,586] INFO [Producer clientId=connector-producer-test-location-connector-0] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1189)
[2021-02-11 01:19:23,410] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=test-location-connector-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:481)
[2021-02-11 01:19:23,411] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=test-location-connector-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:498)
[2021-02-11 01:19:33,416] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=test-location-connector-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:481)
```

Comment: How did you restart connector?

Comment: Probably ctrl+c does not disconnect the connector from Debezium service. You should try deleting the connector (curl -X DELETE "<debezium_service_location>/test-location-connector-0"), and, then, recreate it.

Comment: The first time command is ```/connect-standalone /worker.properties /mysql-connector.properties```, (the connector plugin path is set up in the worker.properties) and I stopped it with Crtl + C, and I restarted it with the same command. When you talking about <debezium_service_location>, I only have a debezium-connector-mysql folder with multiple jar files in it. Is there any detailed information? Thank you guys a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with Debezium 1.5 version, which is in development now. After I switched back to 1.4, and everything works well.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue even with Debezium 1.4.

The fix that worked for me is to **change the `name` of the connector .properties file to something else**.

Now, run the standalone connect command again. It should work.

### How to stop the connector cleanly

It's annoying to keep changing the name each time, but there's a way to avoid that.
Following Vitor's comment, you have to `DELETE` the connector via the [Kafka Connect REST interface](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/restapi.html) *before* doing Ctrl+C. I'll assume you're running standalone on `localhost:8083` (the default).

First check if the Connect REST interface works. I'll use [HTTPie](https://httpie.io/):

```
http GET localhost:8083/connectors
```

If it's working, you should get a list of connector names in a list, like for example

```
[
    "testconnector"
]
```

You should then delete this connector.

```
http DELETE localhost:8083/connectors/testconnector
```

After this, you can finally Ctrl+C. **You may need to restart the Kafka and Zookeeper processes before trying to run Connect again.**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, restarting the connector resolved the problem.

**Listing the Connectors Names:**

```bash
curl -H "Accept:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/
```

**Stopping the Connector:**

```bash
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/<connector-name>/pause
# in your case:
# curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/test-location-connector-0/pause
```

**Starting the Connector**:

```bash
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/$CONNECTOR_NAME/resume
# in your case:
# curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/test-location-connector-0/resume
```